# Отправка сложных объектов клиенту через SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

Код сервера:

```
public class ServerHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var user = new User("Вася петя");

        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("OnConnected", user);
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var hub = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:61938/hub").Build();

        hub.On<User>("OnConnected", user =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
        });

        await hub.StartAsync();
    }
```

Проблема в том, что такие простые типы как int, string и тд. принимаются клиентом, а более сложные типы нет. Как это решить?

Comment: Сериализовать в JSON и слать как `string`. `string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(user)`, а при приеме `User user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(json)`.

Comment: Я не понимаю, иногда мой способ срабатывает, иногда нет. Но твой способ тоже работает